# Running stanbol 0.9.0 incubating version throw Failed To start OSGI framework

Tags: java, osgi, apache-stanbol

> I am trying to run apache stanbol 0.9.0 incubating version.I run mvn
>   install -DskipTests that finished successfully. After building
>   dependency but whenever I tried to run
>   ***org.apache.stanbol.launcher.full-0.9.0-incubating.jar***.

**Output**

```
> 16.11.2018 03:47:06.955 *INFO* [main] Checking launcher JAR in folder sling
> 16.11.2018 03:47:06.964 *INFO* [main] Existing launcher is up to date, using it: 2.3.0 (org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.jar)
> 16.11.2018 03:47:06.965 *INFO* [main] Loading launcher class org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.app.MainDelegate from
> org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.jar
> 16.11.2018 03:47:06.972 *INFO* [main] Starting launcher ...
> 16.11.2018 03:47:06.973 *INFO* [main] HTTP server port: 8080
> 16.11.2018 03:47:07.041 *ERROR* [main] Failed to Start OSGi framework org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Uncaught Instantiation Issue:
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1  at
> org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.impl.Sling.<init>(Sling.java:245)     at
> org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.app.MainDelegate$1.<init>(MainDelegate.java:159)
>   at
> org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.app.MainDelegate.start(MainDelegate.java:159)
>   at org.apache.sling.launchpad.app.Main.startSling(Main.java:244)    at
> org.apache.sling.launchpad.app.Main.<init>(Main.java:107)     at
> org.apache.sling.launchpad.app.Main.main(Main.java:56) Caused by:
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1  at
> java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:422)   at
> java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:435)   at
> org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.getCurrentModule(BundleImpl.java:1046)
>   at
> org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.getSymbolicName(BundleImpl.java:863)
>   at
> org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.impl.SlingFelix.getSymbolicName(SlingFelix.java:32)
>   at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.toString(Felix.java:1012)   at
> org.apache.felix.framework.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:128)  at
> org.apache.felix.framework.Logger._log(Logger.java:181)   at
> org.apache.felix.framework.Logger.log(Logger.java:114)    at
> org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.<init>(ExtensionManager.java:201)
>   at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.<init>(Felix.java:374)  at
> org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.impl.SlingFelix.<init>(SlingFelix.java:39)
>   at org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.impl.Sling.<init>(Sling.java:235)
>   ... 5 more
> 16.11.2018 03:47:07.042 *ERROR* [main] There was a problem launching Sling
> 16.11.2018 03:47:07.042 *INFO* [Sling Terminator] Java VM is shutting down
```

Please help me to sort out this issue. Is this OSGI framework version issue or something else?

Comment: If this happens when following the README in the stanbol repo then the best way to  move forward is to report this as an issue in the issue tracker of stanbol.